# Deployment question regarding App_GlobalResources.compiled

Tags: asp.net

For ASP.NET **Web Site**, when I modifiy resouce files, is it necessary to deploy the **new**   **App_GlobalResources.compiled** along with App_GlobalResources.dll to the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you need to deploy these dll (`App_GlobalResources.dll`
 ), because global resources were built in dll

Follwing files you need to deploy

1. App_global.asax.compiled
2. App_global.asax.dll
3. App_GlobalResources.compiled
4. App_GlobalResources.dll

Comment: Hi actually, my prod server already contained old App_GlobalResources.compiled. Do I need to deploy the new one to server?